# Ajax.BeginForm: disable button while loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Got a working AJAX form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))
```

I want to disable the button while result is loading.
If I use this:

```
$("#submit").click(function () { $("#submit").button().attr('disabled', true).addClass('ui-state-disabled'); })
```

It disables the button, but form doesnt send anything to the controller.
How can I fix that?
(and yes, I barely know how to use JS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) to disable the button.

Comment: can you please explain it deatails

Answer (score 7):

This would do the trick:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

And then if you need to make it enabled when done:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have anything in here (...) -> `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))`

consider using the options to register AjaxOptions
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))

you should have to options at least if you are using the jqery helpers

```
beforeSubmit: CallBackToHandleThinksPreSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
   success: CallBackToHandleThinksPostSubmit// post-submit callback
```

I would register to a callback an make the visibility changes...

HTH

Comment: can you please explain it deatails